# PyQT: clearly displaying number on top of background

Tags: pyqt

I'm trying to display a number on a board with lines (go game). Right now, the number is displayed on top of a cross, so it's not very easy to tell. See the screen shot below

[image]

The background is drawn with `setBackgroundBrush()` on the scene.

The lines are `QGraphicsLineItem` which are added to the scene after the background.

I've tried to display a small portion of the background below the number but the effect isn't great. Is there a smart way of doing this so that when the number is displayed, the area that's covered by the number only shows the background texture and not the lines?

Comment: how do you display the lines? and the text? and the bg?

Comment: Added in the original question

Comment: There's no trivial fix IMHO (but I'm not a regular graphics scene user). You could obviously shorten the lines so that they stop around the numbers, or set some kind of clipping to avoid drawing under numbers. What could also add QGraphicsRect under the numbers, that just show the background brush. The difficulty will be to "sync" the position of your rects' bg brush to the position of the global scene bg brush. Maybe you can reimplement the paint() method to do the sync yourself.